# Error: A type with a full name of 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject' already exists in an included reference (UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2022

Error: A type with a full name of 'Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject' already exists in an included reference.

I am getting this error in my UWP project after i have updated my visual studio 2022 from version 17.3.0 to the latest one.

Before updating my visual studio 2022 (v17.3.0) i didn't have any errors or warnings in my UWP project. After the update i am getting this error and i can't build my project.

I tried refactoring all of the project references and updating some old libraries from nuget but nothing seems to work. The only solution is to go back on my old visual studio version (v17.3.0).

Has anyone else came across this error?

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was updating the target version of my UWP app to the latest version. To do that go to your UWP project properties and on the Application tab change the Target version to Windows 11, version 22H2 (10.0; Build 22621). I kept the Min version the same.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like on mine:

[image]

Hope it works for you!